# Why does Hibernate join unrelated entities on save()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my Spring Boot 2.1.8 project I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@Where(clause = "active = true")
class TeacherEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public String id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "active")
  public boolean active;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "name")
  public String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
class CourseEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
  public TeacherEntity teacher;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "seat")
class SeatEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  public CourseEntity course;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "blabla")
  public String blabla;
}
```

The situation: a SeatEntity was created and persisted, for a valid Course having a valid Teacher. Later, we loaded the SeatEntity from the database, modified its `blabla` field, and tried to save it.

```
public void updateSeats() {
  List<SeatEntity> seats = seatRepository.findAllBy____();
  seats.forEach(seat -> {
    seat.blabla = "new blabla!";
    seat = seatRepository.save(seat); // Exception if Teacher.active = false!
  });
}
```

The exception I get is:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   com.company.TeacherEntity with id 5770d5e3-d7e8-401e-84c5-bb3d83e2e484
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1298)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1161)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
>           at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:226)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:160)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1179)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1028)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2401)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4312)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:570)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:538)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1298)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1161)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
>           at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:226)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:160)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1179)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1028)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)

Why is Hibernate complaining about loading a two-off joined table that has nothing to do with the data I'm trying to save? What is the solution to this issue? Do I need to write a native update query to sidestep the pointless join and save the data?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the data you're trying to save? Your `SeatEntity` depends on `CourseEntity` which depends on `TeacherEntity`. It has everything to do with it, but your `@Where` clause prevents non-active teachers from being loaded. You're trying to save incomplete data, and it's because **you** designed it that way. Maybe you shouldn't have the `@Where` annotation, since it bit you in the backside right away.

Comment: I'm trying to update a column on the `seat` table. I already have the entity. Why would I waste my time joining other tables when all that needs to happen is a simple `UPDATE seat...WHERE id=xxx`

Comment: Not to mention : 1. I didn't personally design it this way (you've never inherited someone else's code?) 2. The @Where annotation has been in production for quite awhile now without other ill effects, so it didn't "bite me right away" 3. The question specifically asks for why Hibernate is doing joins when all that needs to happen is to update a single @Basic column. If anything, I would expect this to fail on the `findAllBy____` call, not the `save()` - what is `save()` doing (concerning the `Teacher`) that it shouldn't already have done?

Comment: I've never inherited homework, because that's what Teacher, Course and Seat sound like. The mapping defines a dependency, and Hibernate is checking that the dependency is being satisfied (i.e. seat is linked to a course which is linked to a teacher). If it didn't check that dependency, it would allow saving broken data. You may learn more about the wonderful and less than wonderful world of Object Relational Mapping by grabbing a book and reading about it. You can of course update it with a native query, but the ORM is doing its job (correctly too, mind you).

Comment: Don't think you get to enjoy the benefits of ORM without having to understand anything about how it works.

Comment: Sorry, but your hypotheses about who I am and what this is for are both wrong. If the data is broken, then why did Hibernate give it to me like that in the first place? Also, in case you didn't notice, there is no cascading going on here, so once again: why is updating a single column causing Hibernate to go joining unreleated tables?

Comment: But they're not unrelated tables. The data isn't broken, and Hibernate is making sure it stays that way. It's not about cascading, it's about non-optional dependencies. You can't save an entity without non-optional dependencies. Your `@Where` prevents one from being loaded. Therefore you can load the seat (which loads the course, but not the teacher if it's inactive), but you can't save it afterwards.

Comment: It DOES load the Teacher (verified via debugger). It appears that the @Where is not applied for joins, but does apply for loading. This still doesn't explain why Hibernate is throwing an exception due to (re-)loading a join of a join, on an Entity that it loaded for me without a problem, and on which the only change was an update of a local column.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was solved by wrapping the method in a transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void updateSeats() {
  // same code as above
}
```

By having the load and save in the same transaction, Hibernate no longer attempts to reload the entire entity graph.